# Typeorm Repository API Join 3 Tables A-AB-B-BC-C

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, typeorm

I would like to join 3 tables with typeorm (mysql database is connected to my nodejs service)
I can easily join 2 or more tables with relations if they join the first table.

But I currently need to join the third table to the second table.
In Sql:

```
SELECT * FROM ReType 
left join relation_ReType_CS 
on relation_ReType_CS.ReTypeId = ReType.id (this join is because manytomany relation)
left join CS 
on CS.id = relation_ReType_CS.CSId 
left join CStype 
on CStype.id = CS.CStype_id
```

So it works in the database with this statement
but something like

```
  const reTypes = await reTypeRepository.find({
            relations: [                    
                'CS',
                'CSType',
            ],
        });
```

does not work in my routes.

I also cant copy the relation out of the CS Entity for CSType to the ReType Entity because it has to be on the CS value for my apollo server on my api gateway.

Thank you.

Comment: Found the answer for those, who are seeking wisdom.
You can do something like: 
const reTypes = await reTypeRepository.find({
            relations: [                    
                'CS',
                'CS.CSType',
            ],
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for those, who are seeking wisdom. You can do something like: const reTypes = await reTypeRepository.find({ relations: [ 'CS', 'CS.CSType', ], });